# Installation of Crossrider extension fails on Windows due to Suspicious.Cloud.9

Tags: windows, installation, crossrider, symantec, trojan

I'm not able to install the browser extension, which is based on the Crossrider API, on a computer with Windows OS. The antivirus software by **Symantec** warns of a trojan/virus named “**Suspicious.Cloud.9**” (see picture below).

I guess there is no possibility to change the generation of the Windows install wizard, except requesting a code signing certificate. Crossrider suggests three certification agencies and of them is Symantec itself.

Has/Had anyone the same or a similar problem? Will code signing solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!
Niels

[image: Symantec summary]
[image: Symantec technical details]

Answer (score 2):

Yes... i know of this issue,  Suspicious Cloud 9 and Suspicious Pythia, Which you may also encounter, ARE NOT viruses or Worms, they are Merely a Message that Symantec Generates to simply say "we consider this software suspicious or suspect"  and it MAY (MAY being the operative word) Contain Viruses, Now as to the reason why it considers it suspicious, the reasons are many, usually the software doesn't have a lot of Downloads behind it and is therefore untrusted Stuff Like that, You can add an exception in Norton for these things. so that it does install. the other way to do it is to disable Norton During the install, and When it detects it later, allow the instance and Norton will automatically create an exception.  Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm able to install the extension and now I'm thinking a little further: I want to distribute my extension to customers, who could have an anti virus software like Symantec running on their system. Can you tell me, if code signing then makes Symantec accept the installation of my extension?

Comment: No. i don't believe it does, Symantec would have to approve the Extension and Make the change in their software and action it via a Live update, You would have to speak to Symantec about having your Extension not trigger their Software as suspecting Suspicious Cloud or Suspicious Pythia, if you want to distribute this extension, You can talk to symantec about becoming a Trusted Software Provider, that's your best bet.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I just requested a whitelisting at Symantec. If you wish, I'll keep you informed about what will happen! ;)

Comment: No Worries, YES Please do let me know what happens, thanks, be cool

Comment: Here is the result of the software white-listing request:

"Upon further analysis and investigation we have determined that the following file(s) meet the necessary criteria to be detected by our products and, as such, the detection(s) cannot be revoked"

So, do you know, if a code signing would help white-listing my extension?

Comment: No, if symantec don't approve it, then you don't have a solution. Unfortunately, thanks for updating me with the results.